# How do I get sub-list from the actual array-list using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

How do I get sublist from the actual arraylist using streams and perform data operations on result.

```
I have a pojo class
abc{
rowNum,
startDate,
endDate,
name,
Id
}
```

I am have an arraylist of below data format.

```
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2018-01-01, endDate=2018-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
abc [ rowNum=46, startDate=2020-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Java, Id=456]
abc [ rowNum=46, startDate=2020-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Java, Id=456]
abc [ rowNum=46, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Java, Id=456]
abc [ rowNum=58, startDate=2021-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Sun, Id=678]
abc [ rowNum=58, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Sun, Id=678]

..... 10,000 records.
```

How do I loop for rowNum=1 from the list and perform some logic on data and then goto rowNum=46 and so on...like grouping rowNum..

```
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2018-01-01, endDate=2018-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
abc [ rowNum=1, startDate=2019-01-01, endDate=2099-12-31, name= Testing, Id=101]
```

How do I get sublist from the actual arraylist using streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "grouping by" collector to create a map of instances grouped by row, where the row number is the key in the map. See [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

```
Map<Integer, List<Abc>> byRows = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum));
```

Comment: How do I iterate/loop over above Map<Integer, List<Abc>> to print each element.

Comment: @user5982569 use can use `byRows.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("key: " + k + " & value: " + v));`

Comment: The above statement gives me output: key: 1 & value: [Term@26e04050, Term@dbb56d97]
key: 3 & value: [Term@b77a0c8e, Term@edb8a37]